# VB.net Try Catch. Keep the Loop after the Catch

Tags: vb.net, loops, listbox, try-catch

I'm using Try Catch and I want to add into `Form3.ListBoxes` the items that are into `Form2.ListBoxes` in other type. But it stop adding after the `Catch` the exception. So I want to keep the `Loop` after the exception be caught!

My program get products and show the same products but in another type (Like: I  have a T-shirt with a brand, but I want the "same" T-shirt in another brand).

ListBox5 are the quantity that I add in Form1. I load Images to be clearly. Form2 Listboxes are in order (ListBox1,ListBox2...). Form2 and Form3 have the same design.

```
Dim ConnectionString As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Tabela_Precos.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        ConnectionString.Open()

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da

For i = 0 To Form1.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim str As String = Form1.ListBox1.Items(i).ToString
        Dim prod As String = str.Substring(2, 3)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Mesa$] WHERE Format([Ref], ""000000000"") like '%" & prod & "%'", ConnectionString)

        da.Fill(dt)
        Try
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))
            ListBox2.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(1))
            ListBox3.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(3))
            ListBox4.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(5))
            ListBox5.Items.Add(Form1.ListBox5.Items(i))
            ListBox6.Items.Add(ListBox4.Items(i) * ListBox5.Items(i))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
```

I need the Try-Catch. I'm doing a Query and if doesn't exist the line in DataBase it stop. How can I keep doing the Loop, after stop?

These are the images with program running (they are edited):

[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDzWh.png)

[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cMcA.png)

[Form3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbaDF.png)

Comment: try using `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo` it may help

Comment: I think helps because I could write the quantity, but still not writing the ones that I know that is Good... But I still prefer the Try Catch

Answer (score 0):

You have answered the question yourself when you say *"keep the loop after the catch"*. You want your loop to **continue**, **resume** or move to the **next** iteration. All of these are VB keywords and I recommend you review [For Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) to understand how a For loop works.

Here is one of a few ways you can accomplish this.

With no error handling, just ignore and continue:

```
Try
    ...
Catch ex As Exception
    Continue For
End Try
```

Comment: I forgot to say. I tried `Continue For` But it doesn't work..., With `Continue For` after `Finally` says "_Branching out of a 'Finally' is not valid_"

Comment: @Silvestre apologies. Removed that. The initial example will do what you need.

Comment: The `Continue For` is not even required here. If an exception is caught, the code will resume with the next statement after `End Try` which is `Next` in your example. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UwAfjZ)

Comment: @Silvestre Debug your code line for line. Debug also over the Exception.

Comment: @AlexB. I'm not much experient, could you explain me better?

Comment: @Silvestre Set a Breakpoint in line `da.Fill(dt)`. Go on step for step now (press F10). Do until the Exception is thrown. The debugger is now in line `Catch ex As Exception`. Step further. It should then pass `End Try` and `Next`. If the last iteration caused the exception (i = Form1.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1), the deubbger is now whatever line after `Next` ist. If not the last iteration, it jumps back to `Dim str As String = Form1.ListBox1.Items(i).ToString`. Anything else would really surprise me.

Comment: Yes. And how could this help me?

Comment: @Silvestre Alex B is explaining how to step through code line-by-line to confirm your code is already looping after the `catch`. If it does not continue after exception is caught, then we need more information about your problem. How do you know it stops at the `catch` statement and does not continue? Also, even though Alex B says `continue for` is not required, did you try it?

Comment: It don't stop, but says that the next has error too. But if I delete the item with error, the items that was next to him, now appears!

Comment: @Silvestre what is the error message(s) you are getting?

Comment: **IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled** `There is no row at position X`

Comment: @Silvestre Well that suggests the problem is you're indexing into the DataTable using the ListItemCollection index i.e. it can't continue because `i` is greater than `dt.Rows.Count`. Resolve that for a start.

Comment: @JonathonOgden I know, if `i` is greater than `dt.Rows,Count` it means that the "same" product doesn't exist in other type! So that he ignore that problem, and should keep looping to write the ones that are correct! But it stop when appears an exception...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105700/discussion-between-jonathonogden-and-silvestre).