# Listbox Items backcolor

Tags: vb.net, listbox, listboxitems

First, I need an answer ( [VB.net Try Catch. Keep the Loop after the Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840187/vb-net-try-catch-keep-the-loop-after-the-catch) ) to do the next **new** problem...

**Read the link above. There I explain everything.**

I want to color the background of the item that got `Catch`, so that I know what Product doesn't exist in the other Type.

What is doing is Painting all the `ListBox`

> **I'm in the Form3:**

```
ConnectionString.Open()

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter

        For i = 0 To Form2.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

            Dim str As String = Form2.ListBox1.Items(i).ToString
            Dim col As String = str.Substring(2, 3)

            If Form1.MESA_btn.Enabled = False Then
                da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Mesa$] WHERE Decor = '" & CB_col.Text & "' and Format([Ref], ""000000000"") like '__" & col & "%'", ConnectionString)
            Else
                da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Gift$] WHERE Decor = '" & CB_col.Text & "' and Format([Ref], ""000000000"") like '__" & col & "%'", ConnectionString)
            End If

            da.Fill(dt)
            Try
                ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))
                ListBox2.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(1))
                ListBox3.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(3))
                ListBox4.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(5))
                ListBox5.Items.Add(Form2.ListBox5.Items.Item(i))
                ListBox6.Items.Add(ListBox4.Items.Item(i) * ListBox5.Items.Item(i))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Form2.ListBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                Form2.ListBox2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                Form2.ListBox3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                Form2.ListBox4.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                Form2.ListBox5.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                Form2.ListBox6.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            End Try
        Next

ConnectionString.Close()
```

These are the images with program running (they are edited):

[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDzWh.png)

[Form2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cMcA.png)

[Form3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbaDF.png)

Comment: Why don't you just paint the background of each listbox when you set the value? then the ones that are left unpainted(white) means the error occured at that point?

Comment: But I only want to paint the one that has an error. So that I could see what's the product that is missing

Comment: can you remove the banner effect caused the by the blockquote please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best method of doing things. Though this could solve your issue.

```
Dim currentList as Object
            Try
                currentList = Form2.ListBox1
                ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))
                currentList = Form2.ListBox2
                ListBox2.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(1))
                currentList = Form2.ListBox3
                ListBox3.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(3))
                currentList = Form2.ListBox4
                ListBox4.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(5))
                currentList = Form2.ListBox5
                ListBox5.Items.Add(Form2.ListBox5.Items.Item(i))
                currentList = Form2.ListBox6
                ListBox6.Items.Add(ListBox4.Items.Item(i) * ListBox5.Items.Item(i))
            Catch ex As Exception
                currentList.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            End Try
```

Comment: It won't resolve the previous problem. Painted all the `ListBox1` of Form3. And I want to paint the `ListBoxes` that is in Form2.

Answer (score 0):

It does what it says on the tin. You asked to paint whole ListBox and it paints it all.

I would suggest to use DataGridView instead of ListBox. If set:

```
Me.DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
Me.DataGridView1.MultiSelect = False
```

It will look and behave pretty much similar to a ListBox. You can then set:

```
Me.DataGridView1.row(ir).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
```

and thus paint individual rows without any troubles.